# iOS Push Notifications with Parse Platform - didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken - never called

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, back4app

I'm new to iOS development. I'm having trouble getting push notifications to work. I'm following this guide: https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/push-notifications/ios-send-push-notification-from-server

The behavior is that, in the simulator the callback didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError does happen (as expected).

When I run on the phone, neither didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken or didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError are ever called. I've tried installing and uninstalling, moving code around etc. etc. etc.

Here's my code in AppDelegate.swift

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let userNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    userNotificationCenter.delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("D'oh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
                               $0.applicationId = "actual"
                               $0.clientKey = "actual"
                               $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
                               $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true
                           }
            Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }

        }
    }

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

    if let user = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user"),let pwd = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "pwd"){
        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: user as! String, password: pwd as! String) { (user, error) in
//                print(user)
        }
    }


    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("Registered.")
    createInstallationOnParse(deviceTokenData: deviceToken)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register: \(error)")
}

func createInstallationOnParse(deviceTokenData:Data){
    if let installation = PFInstallation.current(){
        installation.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceTokenData)
        installation.saveInBackground {
            (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if (success) {
                print("You have successfully saved your push installation to Back4App!")
            } else {
                if let myError = error{
                    print("Error saving parse installation \(myError.localizedDescription)")
                }else{
                    print("Uknown error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}


}
```

[Signing & Capabilities Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6185F.png)

[Apple Developer Certs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJFGy.png)

Comment: Update: I was able to get notifications on my spouses device, I'm still trying to get my own phone to work. Mine is an iPhone 7 is there something specific to it?

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest resetting your devises permission for your App. Follow these steps:**

1. Delete the App from your device
2. Go to the Settings App -> General -> Date and Time -> Set the time to be one day ahead
3. Restart your device
4. Reinstall your App

Your permissions for that App should all be reset now, in theory when opening the App you should get alerts for the permissions you need to request and upon granting those your code should run through the logic of registering for remote notifications.